# Проблемы с criteria запросом в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

По id достаю но по sql или hql и criteria выходит NPE.и при отображении в jsp вместо букв знаки вопроса..пробовал настроить файл server.xml в tomcat в UTF-8 , src,jsp все в кодировке UTF-8.spring 4.1.1 hibernate 4.3.5 .помогите пожалуйста.уже третий день мучаюсь. а вот код.

```
**MAIN.JS**

            $('#button2').click(
             function(){

             $.ajax({
             url:"getcity",
             type : "GET",
             contentType:"application/text",

             success:function(City){
             if(City!=null){

             $('#result').html(City);
             }else{$('#result').html("ОШИБКААААААА!!!!!");}

             }
             })
             })



**CONTROLLER**

            @ResponseBody
             @RequestMapping(value = "/getcity",method = RequestMethod.GET)
             public String getCityPoSql() {

             cities cit = cityService.getCity();


             return"<h1>" + cit.toString() + "</h1>";
             }
             }

**DAO**

            @Transactional(readOnly = true)
             public cities getCity() {

             Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(cities.class);


             criteria.add(eq("city", "Москва"));
             cities cit =(cities) criteria.uniqueResult();

             return cit ;
             }
            }
```

### cityService не null..а getCity возвращает null..база в UTF-8 ///config sessionFactory..

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"> <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cities</value> </property>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.plan.model"/>
           <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

               </props>
           </property>
    </bean>
```

#### если в criteria запросе вот так написать :собственно так и есть

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public cities getCityIdSql() {

   Criteria criteria =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(cities.class);

       cities cit =(cities) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("city","Москва")).uniqueResult();

       return cit ;
   }
}
```

#### должен  ли возвращать все остальные поля где city равна Москва..в моем случае это строка и возвращает NPE.такое поле есть и значение такое

```
**Stacktrace**

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        com.plan.pn.cityController.getCityPoSql(cityController.java:42)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/7.0.14
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите stack trace.

Comment: @Slava Semushin добавил

Comment: Также понадобится, как минимум: 1) настройки Hibernate, в частности нам инересны настройки подключения к БД 2) Какую БД используете? 3) В какой кодировке сохранены данные в таблице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте сначала решим проблему с `NullPointerException`: судя по stack trace исключение происходит на этих строчках

```
     cities cit = cityService.getCity();
     return"<h1>" + cit.toString() + "</h1>";
```

Поэтому есть два варианта, которые надо проверить/исправить:

- `cityService` не `null`
- `cityService.getCity()` возвращает `null`

Comment: cityService не null; а cityService.getCity null;

Comment: Тогда хорошо бы увидеть как выглядит метод `cityService.getCity()`.

Comment: надеюсь я вам не надоел..добавил метод..

Comment: Вот подобный же вопрос на StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036965/hibernate-uniqueresult-silently-fails Говорят, что `uniqueResult()` возвращает `null` когда запрос к БД ничего не вернул. Поэтому вам нужно добавить проверку на этот случай и, как советуют, включить логгирование и посмотреть какой реально запрос к БД исполняется и почему он ничего не возвращает.

Comment: я думал вот это строка

Comment: criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("city", "Москва")).uniqueResult();

Comment: равна   SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE CITY="Москва"

Comment: пошел учить criteria